# How does REMOTE_USER Authentication Type works in apache superset?

Tags: python, flask-appbuilder, apache-superset

I've been trying to authenticate with my Login Rest API instead of Other types. How to achieve this? Is REMOTE_USER authentication is the right way to do it? If so, can I get a sample code or documentation on this?

Read the docs [here](http://flask-appbuilder.readthedocs.io/en/latest/security.html#supported-authentication-types) but couldn't understand much since I'm new to flask-appbuilder and python.

Comment: did you manage to figure this problem out?

Comment: No.. left it off, never continued implementing it...

Answer (score 3):

Just for next ones arriving here.

Followed instructions here: https://superset.incubator.apache.org/installation.html#middleware

But not working: TOO MANY REDIRECTS.

Flask App-Builder code here: 
https://github.com/dpgaspar/Flask-AppBuilder/blob/167c13ec6dda6e7d8286e590233cd603a7d13928/flask_appbuilder/security/views.py#L728

Finally made my own custom remote login (Draft version below).

```
# Apache superset REMOTE_USER authentication
# https://superset.incubator.apache.org/installation.html#middleware
from flask_appbuilder.security.manager import AUTH_REMOTE_USER

# Define AUTH_TYPE
# AUTH_TYPE = AUTH_REMOTE_USER

# Allow users to auto register and be assigned to Remote role
# AUTH_USER_REGISTRATION = True
# AUTH_USER_REGISTRATION_ROLE = "Remote"

# For testing without a proxy just calling http://localhost:9000/superset/welcome?logme=user1
from flask import request, g
from flask_login import login_user, logout_user
import logging


# Middleware to extract user from header HTTP_X_PROXY_REMOTE_USER
# and place it at REMOTE_USER
class RemoteUserLogin(object):

    def __init__(self, app):
        self.app = app

    def log_user(self, environ):
        from superset import security_manager as sm

        username = self.get_username(environ)
        logging.info("REMOTE_USER Checking logged user")
        if hasattr(g, "user") and \
            hasattr(g.user, "username"):
            if g.user.username == username:
                logging.info("REMOTE_USER user already logged")
                return g.user
            else:
                logout_user()

        user = sm.find_user(username=username)
        logging.info("REMOTE_USER Look up user: %s", user)
        if user:
            logging.info("REMOTE_USER Login_user: %s", user)
            login_user(user)
        return user

    def get_username(self, environ):
        user = environ.pop('HTTP_X_PROXY_REMOTE_USER', None)

        if not user and self.app.debug:
             # Dev hack 
            user = environ.get("werkzeug.request").args.get("logme")
            if user:
                logging.error("Logging user from request. Remove me ASAP!!!: %s", user)

        environ['REMOTE_USER'] = user
        return user

    def before_request(self):
        user = self.log_user(request.environ)
        if not user:
            raise Exception("Invalid login or user not found")


from superset.app import SupersetAppInitializer
def app_init(app):
    logging.info("Resgistering RemoteUserLogin")
    app.before_request(RemoteUserLogin(app).before_request)
    return SupersetAppInitializer(app)

APP_INITIALIZER = app_init
```

Answer (score 3):

For simple cases, add the below snippet to `superset_config.py` as mentioned [here](https://github.com/apache/superset/blob/master/docs/installation.rst#middleware):

```
class RemoteUserMiddleware(object):
    def __init__(self, app):
        self.app = app
    def __call__(self, environ, start_response):
        user = environ.pop('HTTP_X_PROXY_REMOTE_USER', None)
        environ['REMOTE_USER'] = user
        return self.app(environ, start_response)

ADDITIONAL_MIDDLEWARE = [RemoteUserMiddleware, ]
AUTH_TYPE = AUTH_REMOTE_USER
AUTH_USER_REGISTRATION = True
```

and configure the reverse proxy to add the username (or email) to a header named `X-PROXY-REMOTE-USER` (without the `HTTP`). Enabling `AUTH_USER_REGISTRATION` is important so that the account gets created automatically if it doesn't exist.

This will call the [AuthRemoteUserView](https://github.com/dpgaspar/Flask-AppBuilder/blob/167c13ec6dda6e7d8286e590233cd603a7d13928/flask_appbuilder/security/views.py#L728) view, which in turn calls [auth_user_remote_user](http://%20https://github.com/dpgaspar/Flask-AppBuilder/blob/c59b4136d6036d53ff1af33e14385b5a86121b7a/flask_appbuilder/security/manager.py#L1242) to find and create a user if it doesn't exist.

If you want to customize this to add email, usernames, and possibly do rbac based on groups, you can extend the above view like so:

```
class CustomRemoteUserView(AuthRemoteUserView):
    [...]

class CustomSecurityManager(SupersetSecurityManager):
    authremoteuserview = CustomRemoteUserView

CUSTOM_SECURITY_MANAGER = CustomSecurityManager
```

Comment: For anyone else which has problems with this, note that something in the process changes all "-" to "_" in the HTTP header! So if the header is e.g. "X-MS-CLIENT-PRINCIPAL-NAME" you must pop "HTTP_X_MS_CLIENT_PRINCIPAL_NAME" !